# Adding sprite to a node

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I've got a `SpritePlayer` class, which holds my sprite.

`SpritePlayer.h:`

```
class SpritePlayer : public cocos2d::Node
{
public:
    SpritePlayer();
    CREATE_FUNC(SpritePlayer);
    void InitSpritePlayer(std::string pathToSptire);
    cocos2d::Sprite *GetSprite();
(...)
private:
    cocos2d::Sprite *_sprite;
}
```

`SpritePlayer.cpp:`

```
void SpritePlayer::InitSpritePlayer(std::string pathToSprite)
{
    _sprite = cocos2d::Sprite::create(pathToSprite);
}

cocos2d::Sprite *SpritePlayer::GetSprite()
{
    return _sprite;
}
(...)
```

At `MainScene.cpp` I've got:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    playerSpritesList[i] = &SpritePlayer();
    playerSpritesList[i]->InitSpritePlayer("ch2.png");
    this->addChild(playerSpritesList[i]->GetSprite(), 0);
    //SpritePlayersNode->addChild(playerSpritesList[i]->GetSprite())
}
```

And now the question - how could I add this sprite to a node?
Both bottom lines are causing errors, because I have to pass a `Node` into `addChild()` function.

Comment: Before I post an answer I want to ask why you did not inherit directly from sprite? This will allow you to use the inherited initialize functionality already build into sprite. You seem to be adding a layer of abstraction that currently to me looks like it's serving no purpose. What is your intention for this object?

Comment: I was looking at another class which I already had while writing this one. Are you suggesting, that class SpritePlayer should inherit from sprite?
Anyway, I will still need to convert Sprite into Node somehow, to add it to scene.

Comment: Sprite is a node, you have no don't need to convert anything. I'll post an answer to your question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are going about it is introducing a level of abstraction that you do not need to have. The character itself can be a sprite, the way you have it your SpriteCharacter is not actually a sprite, it's a manager for a character sprite. I usually use the following pattern.

**Character.h**

```
class Character : public cocos2d::Sprite
{
 public:
  Character* createCharacterSprite(Vec2 position, std::string fileName);
 private:
  Character();
}
```

**Character.cpp**

```
Character* Character::createCharacterSprite(Vec2 position, std::string fileName)
{
  auto character = new Character();
  if(character && character->initWithFile(fileName))
  {
    character->autorelease();
    return character;
  }
}
```

**MainScene.cpp**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  auto character = Character::createCharacterSprite(characterPosition, "filename.png");
  this->addChild(character);
}
```

This way you can manipulate from within CharacterSprite using 'this' instead of a pointer to your actual character sprite. Positioning and animations will also become a lot easier since you won't have another node with a possible different anchor point in between your character and your MainScene layer.

Answer (score 1):

Sprite is a subclass of Node so there's not a problem with using addChild. 
This line is suspicious:

```
playerSpritesList[i] = &SpritePlayer();
```

I'd remove SpritePlayer() constructor from your code, because CREATE_FUNC(SpritePlayer) creates default one, which manages memory. And then you can call playerSpritesList[i] = SpritePlayer::create();

Also you can write USING_NS_CC; in SpritePlayer (beware of Point struct - you have to write cocos2d::Point, because of namespace conflict on iOS/Mac).

Also for convention function names should start with lower case :)